# What does the word TREESAME mean in the context of git?

Tags: git

I saw many references to `TREESAME` in the git log manual.
But I did not know what it meant.

Answer (score 3):

Given two or more trees, a pathspec is considered `TREESAME` if and only if there is no discernible difference for the pathspec among the respective trees.

More intuitively, one could think of `TREESAME` as meaning *the same between trees*.

Answer (score 2):

As defined in the same [git-log manual](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) you mentioned:

> Suppose you specified foo as the `<paths>`. We shall call commits that modify foo !TREESAME, and the rest TREESAME. (In a diff filtered for foo, they look different and equal, respectively.)

Comment: Could really do with a more simple / alternative explanation. I read the docs and it still doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Adding a snippet from the manual doesn't help if important surrounding context is removed.

Answer (score 1):

### Primer: Git tree objects and references

Every commit in git includes 4 fundamental pieces of data:

1. The commit hash.
2. Any parent commits (an empty set for the initial commit).
3. Commit metadata including author, committer, and the commit message.
4. A tree object reference.

Most developers are familiar with the first 3, but the tree object reference isn't well known, probably because it's very well hidden by default - it doesn't even show with `--format=full` or `--format=fuller` options to `git show` / `git log` / etc.

To see the tree hash associated with each commit, use the `--format=raw` option (or include `%T`/`%t` in your format spec) in commands such as `git show --format=raw` or `git log --format="format:commit:%h tree:%T %s"`.

Separate commits can reference any tree object in the repository, including those referenced by other commits.

The `git ls-tree <tree-ish>` command shows you the contents of a tree object.  The output format is `<mode> SP <type> SP <object> TAB <file>`. Mode reflects the file type (eg: regular file or symlink), permissions (eg: user/group/world read/write/execute), etc. Type is either `tree` for directories (trees are recursive structures), or `blob` for everything else.  Use `git cat-file -p <object>` to pretty-print the content of any object.  *Keen observers will note the lack of any time related metadata, and hence why file modified/created times aren't updated by git.*

Now that you're up to speed on how commits relate to trees, and what's in a tree, we can truly understand the answer to your question.

### What does the word TREESAME mean in the context of git?

Any commits that reference the same tree object (with the same tree hash) are TREESAME.

The TREESAME concept can also be applied to specific paths within a tree - this is how `git log <path>` chooses which commits to show for a given path. See the section on [History Simplification](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_history_simplification) in the git docs for more details.

Comment: Everything was going really well until we lost control of the vehicle and crashed.  "Branches are TREESAME if their HEAD commits reference the same tree object". Rank nonsense. A branch _is_ one commit, and that's _all_ it is. Two branches are either the same commit or two different commits; if one, they are trivially treesame, and if two, they are or are not treesame. The end. Branches don't have HEAD commits.  There is only one HEAD commit and it might or might not be a branch. I would just delete the sentence; the previous sentence says what you wanted to say.

Comment: @matt Last sentence removed.

Comment: Cool. This is now an excellent explanation. Just one caveat: The Git docs use TREESAME with respect to a specific path (file) within a commit's tree, not just the tree as a whole. If A has foo and bar, and its child B has foo unmodified but bar modified, then B and A are not treesame as a whole, but they _are_ treesame with respect to foo. And this is not just a quibble; that sort of case is exactly what the `git log` documentation is concerned with in most uses of the term. Plain and simple, two commits are treesame with respect to foo if they "contain" the same foo.

Comment: Please note that that is exactly what https://stackoverflow.com/a/45315334/341994 is trying to say. What you want to do is to say that, less cryptically.

Comment: @matt Thanks for your tips. I've added details on how the TREESAME concept can be applied to paths, but I'm reluctant to add any more as it's already a lot to digest for those that are new to the TREESAME concept.

Comment: @matt When I said "Branches are TREESAME if their HEAD commits reference the same tree object", the term "commits" refers to the plurality of commit A from branch FOO, and commit B from branch BAR - there are multiple branches, and hence multiple commits.  I was not suggesting there are multiple commits at the tip of any particular branch, but indeed I could have worded it better.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247020/discussion-between-tyson-and-matt).

Comment: I repeat, branches don't have HEADs. HEAD is something _you_ have; it's the currently checked out commit. And so  there is only one HEAD. Sometimes we say branches have tips, but that too is wrong; the branch _is_ the tip. A branch is a name for one commit, and that's all it is.