# Best way to avoid merging a branch into another one

Tags: git, merge

We at work have three branches

- master
- release
- develop

We develop into branches based on the `develop` one, when finished, we merge that develop into the `release` one for the application to be tested. Meanwhile, we keep developing and merging things in `develop`.

One's `release` is tested, we make a merge into `master`. We never should merge develop directly into master and we want to avoid human factor accidents automatically.

Is there a git way to make branches incompatibles so any attempt to merge one into another is rejected? Is there a plugin or something?

Comment: My first thought was "git hooks", but, apparently, there isn't a "pre-merge" hook. Second thought: maybe you shouldn't fight the convention? `master` is a "special" branch name. It's a default target branch for Pull Requests, etc. One could say, branches are _meant_ to be merged to master.

Comment: As for the actual question, even if you're not successful in _preventing_ such merges, I'm sure that it's possible to _detect_ them after the fact (and undo manually, or something).

Comment: "One's release is tested, we make a merge into master" --> everywhere i've seen it's the other way around... test in master and then make a release

Comment: May be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21623699/is-it-possible-to-get-a-list-of-merges-into-a-branch-from-the-github-website-or

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet to really enforce this is to install a `pre-receive` hook on the receiving end (i.e., in your central "push" repository).

As per https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks :

> The first script to run when handling a push from a client
>   is pre-receive. It takes a list of references that are being pushed
>   from stdin; if it exits non-zero, none of them are accepted. You can
>   use this hook to do things like make sure none of the updated
>   references are non-fast-forwards, or to do access control for all the
>   refs and files they’re modifying with the push.

Check the documentation and the example hooks in `.git/hooks/*.sample`, you should be able to put something together (i.e., go through the references you got as command line parameters, check whether each of them contains one of your invalid merges, and `exit 1` if it did). Let us know if you can't seem to get it to work.

To find out whether you want to accept the merge, you can get creative with `git log`.